# Print a dictionary with certain format in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have created a dictionary (dynamic) to be able to create an automated tree structure in my worksheet.

I already have the dictionary and I want to print it with a certain layout. 
I will explain this with an example:

Let's say I have the following dictionary, in which the values for every key are classes with different variables:

Dictionary structure:

```
{key:class containing (name, if it is active/not, a dictionary with the 
keys of nodes inside this key)}
```

My example:

```
{1:(Parent 1, Active, {2,3,4}),2:(Child 1,Active,{}),3:(Child 2,Active, 
{}),4:(Parent 2,Active,{5}),5:(Child 3,Active,{6,7}),6:(Grandchild 
1,Active,{}),7:(Grandchild 2,Active,{})}
```

I want to display it with a format similar to this (writing the code in VBA):

[image]

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your vba code please?

Comment: I know you want this in the worksheet, but in case it's helpful you might want to check out https://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/treeview.asp

Comment: Do you need the code for the dictionary creation? I can provide it but I dont thing that is helping... @QHarr

Comment: There's also a really great article on dictionaries at https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3391/Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html that I refer to often, that has some examples of writing dictionaries to the sheet.

Comment: @jeffreyweir Thanks, the article is really usefull but still I cannot see how to solve this